# ContentResolver.isSyncActive on Android 5.0 throws IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, synchronization, illegalargumentexception

I have been using [isSyncActive()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#isSyncActive%28android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String%29) to check is sync active. Everything working well on Android versions < 5.0 but on new android version 5.0 it throws exception `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: account must not be null`. Is there any solution and why is this happening only in the above mentioned android version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code for the content resolver is open source: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/content/ContentResolver.java if you are interested. I'm also having trouble with other things associated with the 5.0 update, which is why I happened across this post. Looks like you need to pass a valid account object to the method to get it to work.

```
public static boolean isSyncActive(Account account, String authority) {
    if (account == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("account must not be null");
    }
    if (authority == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("authority must not be null");
    }

    try {
        return getContentService().isSyncActive(account, authority, null);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("the ContentService should always be reachable", e);
    }
}
```